# changing the decimal point for a specific language

Tags: react-intl

we are using the react-intl (ver 5.21) to display currency.

the result will be:
123.45
But if let say I want to change the decimal separator for en-us to be , (comma):
123,45
Is it possible in global scope?
I cannot change the local and must send USD as display value.

I looked in the documentation and try to find a way to override a specific local with new appearance (in my case, replace the decimal point (.) with comma (,)